# Asp.net Page and control Events

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

I have looked all over the web and I can not find the information I am looking for and I was hoping that someone could give me a hand.

Specifically, I am looking for a comprehensive list of what events occur in the page and control life cycles and what is "available" in each event.  Like when can I get a dropdownlists selected value, when can i databind, when can I get at values in view state and what not.  Can anyone point me to a comprehensive list for both page and control life cycles? Or even provide that information for me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: here's egg on my face . . . thanks for using your google-fu for me

Answer (score 1):

[image: ASP.NET Page Life-cycle Poster]
<sub>(source: [rioterdecker.net](http://blog.rioterdecker.net/photos/images/images/113/original.aspx))</sub>

Awesome infographic showing the ASP.NET lifecycle from [Avalonboy](https://web.archive.org/web/20150215105402/http://blog.rioterdecker.net/blogs/avalonboy/archive/2006/06/24/114.aspx)